# flutter new created project don't run

Tags: flutter

just created new flutter project with the command `flutter create test`.
When start it failed with this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'D:\sandbox\mobile-app\sheba\testapp\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\grebe\.gradle\caches\7.4\scripts\ea4ydi90mwjg9g63m7r6nimmx).
> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 63

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

Device: Emulated Android 12

Flutter doctor output is:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.10, on Microsoft Windows [version 10.0.22621.1105], locale fr-FR)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Build Tools 2019 16.11.15)
[!] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
    X Unable to find bundled Java version.
[√] VS Code (version 1.74.3)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Thanks for help :)

Comment: please share you flutter doctor out put

Comment: [!] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    X Unable to find bundled Java version.
    • Try updating or re-installing Android Studio.

Comment: please edit your question and paste your whole flutter doctor output there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
run " --flutter doctor " and share the result
```

is it your first project with flutter on your device ?

Also mention what is your device and it's OS version.

Problem: `[!] Android Studio (version 2022.1) X Unable to find bundled Java version.`

answer : `Go to "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio" and then copy the content of jbr and paste the content into jre folder run doctor again`

Comment: Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.10, on Microsoft Windows [version 10.0.22621.1105], locale fr-FR)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Build Tools 2019 16.11.15)
[!] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
    X Unable to find bundled Java version.
[√] VS Code (version 1.74.3)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.

Comment: ok Go to  "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio" and then copy the content of jbr and paste the content into jre folder

run doctor again

Comment: Your welcome bro , i will add this line to answer, you should also add your flutter doctor result to your question for better experience. also if you enjoyed it give my answer a thumbs up :)

Answer (score 0):

just change your gradle version to 7.6 .
follow the steps 1android>gradle>gradle-property
check  this line distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-**7.6**-all.zip)
this 7.6 should not be 7.4 or less

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).